# How do you set traceflags in dbexpress SQL Monitor

Tags: delphi, dbexpress

Am I right that traceflags do not work in SQLMonitor?  I have been trying to use them in XE2 with Firebird and it looks to me like they have not been implemented at all. The published properties of TSQLMonitor has traceflags commented out.

```
  published
    property Active: Boolean read FActive write SetActive default False;
    property AutoSave: Boolean read FAutoSave write FAutoSave default False;
    property FileName: string read FFileName write SetFileName;
    property OnLogTrace: TTraceLogEvent read FOnLogTrace write FOnLogTrace;
    property OnTrace: TTraceEvent read FOnTrace write FOnTrace;
{   property TraceFlags not supported in DBExpress 1.0 }
    property TraceList: TStrings read FTraceList write SetTraceList stored False;
    property SQLConnection: TSQLConnection read FSQLConnection write SetSQLConnection;
  end;
```

And when they always come through as TraceLevel 5 and TraceFlag 256 in the OnLogTrace and OnTrace events.  I know I can use the DelegateConnection of the TSQLConnection as an alternative but this only traces to a file and I wanted it to come through in a memo.  Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Steve

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the question is here. The posted code snippet clearly says that `TraceFlags` is *not* supported, yet you appear to be asking if it *is* supported. I think the answer should be clear. Am I missing something here?

Comment: It wasn't clear to me.  The documentation on the embarcadero site [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Debugging_dbExpress_Applications) seems to imply that these flags can be used but I don't see how.  I suspect the idea was to set the traceflags property and use that as a bitmask to filter the output.  There is also a trace level that appears to be 5 for everything.

Comment: When in doubt, use the source, Luke... Sorry - Steve. :) Given a choice between what the docs say and the source code on your machine, the source code wins every time.